# RedisTimeoutException in Azure App Service ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, session, redis

I've faced with one strange issue using RedisSessionStateProvider as session provider in ASP.NET MVC application. 
I have next code (simplified a bit) which get image from DB and then store into session but if image is already in session but hash is different - update stored image. If not - just return image from session without get it from DB

```
public FileResult GetImage(
        int entityId,
        string imageHash)
    {
        var storedImage =
            this.ImagesList.FirstOrDefault(
                i => i.EntityId == entityId);
        if (storedImage != null && storedImage.ImageHash == imageHash)
        {
            return this.File(storedImage.Content, "image/png", "Image.png");
        }
        //// Here I get image from DB
        if (storedImage != null)
        {
            //// Here I update image stored in Redis if it's changed
        }
        else
        {
            //// Here I insert image into Redis
        }
        return this.File(resizedImage, "image/png", "Image.png");
    }
```

Where this.ImagesList it's a list of images stored into Session but because I use RedisSessionStateProvider - it's stored into Redis. So I don't work with Redis directly.

Then I get images in a front-end defining src for  as Url to GetImage action of ImageController. It's not good approach as I've found in the end we will remake it but I want to find the reason of time outs because we are going to use Redis Cache as session storage in our application for another needs.

Images size is not big. I don't think that there is image 1 Mb. More likely it's 100Kb max.

So, when I load list of records which have images (15-20 records) very often I get next exception:

> Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 7, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 0,
>   qu: 0, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, clientName:
>   RD00155D62D65A, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/......., keyHashSlot:
>   5043, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=7,Free=8184,Min=1,Max=8191) (Please take a look at this article
>   for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
>   http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

I've read specified in exception article and fixed ThreadPool in Application_Start to setup IOCP min=20 and Workers min=25. But then I get the same exception:

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.Timeout
>   performing EVAL, inst: 1, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 12, qu: 0,
>   qs: 12, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 65536, ar: 0, clientName:
>   RD00155D62D65A, serverEndpoint:
>   Unspecified/....., keyHashSlot:
>   5043, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=20,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=8,Free=8183,Min=25,Max=8191) (Please take a look at this article
>   for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
>   http://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

I've found that the possible issue is next attribute of the exception:

> in: 65536

Which is according [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-troubleshoot#burst-of-traffic) article:

> You can also see in: 64221. This indicates that 64211 bytes have been
>   received at the kernel socket layer but haven't yet been read by the
>   application (e.g. StackExchange.Redis). This typically means that your
>   application isn't reading data from the network as quickly as the
>   server is sending it to you.

But how to handle the issue in my infrastructure - I have not understood yet.